# How do I use transactions or batches to read the value of an update, then perform more updates using that value?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best approach to do a batch update or transaction, that reads a value of the first update, then uses this value to make further updates?

Here is an example:

```
  //create person

  const id = await db
    .collection("person")
    .add({ ...person })
    .then(ref => ref.id)

  //then do a series of updates

  let batch = db.batch()

  const private_doc = db
    .collection("person")
    .doc(id)
    .collection("private")
    .doc("data")

  batch.set(private_doc, {
    last_modified,
    version: 1,
    versions: []
  })

  const some_index = db.collection("data").doc("some_index")

  batch.update(some_index, {
    [id]: { first_name: person.first_name, last_name: person.last_name, last_modified }
  })

  const another_helpful_doc = db.collection("some_other_collection").doc("another_helpful_doc")

  batch.update(another_helpful_doc, {
    [id]: { first_name: person.first_name, last_name: person.last_name, image: person.image }
  })

  return batch.commit().then(() => {
    person.id = id
    return person
  })
```

You can see here if there is an error any of the batch updates, the person doc will still be created - which is bad. I could add in a `catch` to delete the person doc if anything fails, however interested to see if this is possible with transactions or batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [`doc()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#doc) method, without specifying any path, in order to create a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) with an auto-generated ID and, then, use the reference later. Note that the document corresponding to the `DocumentReference` is NOT created.

So, the following would do the trick, since **all** the writes/updates are included in the batched write:

```
const new_person_ref = db.collection("person").doc();
const id = new_person_ref.id;

let batch = db.batch()

batch.set(new_person_ref, { ...person })

const private_doc_ref = db  // <- note the addition of ref to the variable name, it could help avoiding errors, as this is not a DocumentSnapshot but a DocumentReference.
    .collection("person")
    .doc(id)
    .collection("private")
    .doc("data")

batch.set(private_doc_ref, {
    last_modified,
    version: 1,
    versions: []
})

//....
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Renaud - this worked exactly as expected.